# Xpath for the Text under the br tag

Tags: xpath

I have been trying to find the text after the br tag, but so far not been able to do that. Any help with this ?

```
//div[@class='dl-result-item']/*[2]
```

The above is returning the correct Name, but not able to figure out the Address.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try below expression to get required content:

```
//li/div[@class='dl-result-item']/*[not(name()=("a", "div"))]/text()[string-length()>0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
//div[@class='dl-result-item']/*[2]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```